# Pandas: Replacing Non-numeric cells with 0

Tags: python, pandas

I have the Pandas Dataframe in this format

```
0          or LIST requests
1                 us-west-2
2                 1.125e-05
3                         0
4                 3.032e-05
5                         0
6                  7.28e-06
7          or LIST requests
8                   3.1e-07
9                         0
10                        0
11                1.067e-05
12               0.00011983
13                0.1075269
14         or LIST requests
15                us-west-2
16                        0
17                 2.88e-06
18           ap-northeast-2
19                 5.52e-06
20                 6.15e-06
21                 3.84e-06
22         or LIST requests
```

I want to replace all non-numeric cells with 0 in pandas. I am trying some thing like this but nothing works,

```
training_data['usagequantity'].replace({'^([A-Za-z]|[0-9]|_)+$': 0}, regex=True)
```

any hint how can I do this:

Answer (score 16):

You can use the `to_numeric` method, but it's not changing the value in place. You need to set the column to the new values:

```
training_data['usagequantity'] = (
    pd.to_numeric(training_data['usagequantity'],
                  errors='coerce')
      .fillna(0)
    )
```

[to_numeric](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_numeric.html) sets the non-numeric values to `NaNs`, and then the chained [fillna](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) method replaces the `NaNs` with zeros.

Answer (score 8):

Following code can work:

```
df.col =pd.to_numeric(df.col, errors ='coerce').fillna(0).astype('int')
```

Answer (score 4):

#### Setup

```
import pandas as pd
from StringIO import StringIO

text = """0          or LIST requests
1                 us-west-2
2                 1.125e-05
3                         0
4                 3.032e-05
5                         0
6                  7.28e-06
7          or LIST requests
8                   3.1e-07
9                         0
10                        0
11                1.067e-05
12               0.00011983
13                0.1075269
14         or LIST requests
15                us-west-2
16                        0
17                 2.88e-06
18           ap-northeast-2
19                 5.52e-06
20                 6.15e-06
21                 3.84e-06
22         or LIST requests"""

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(text), sep='\s{2,}', engine='python', index_col=[0], header=None)
```

Use `pd.to_numeric`

```
pd.to_numeric(df.iloc[:, 0], errors='coerce').fillna(0)
```

Assign this column where ever you'd like.

Comment: tried, not working. Btw training_data is my dataframe. Thanks

Comment: @HassamSheikh What do you mean "not working"? Do you get an error? An unexpected result? This answer is exactly what your question needs.